# compile error : procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Tags: events, vb6, picturebox

I have copied my entire vb6 code from one machine to another , now when i was running my code on another machine ,it shows error like : compile error : procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name,
This is the code :

```
Private Sub MKDataGrid1_KeyPress()
    If MKDataGrid1.Col = 0 Or MKDataGrid1.Col = 1 Or MKDataGrid1.Col = 2 Or MKDataGrid1.Col = 3 Then
        MKDataGrid1.AllowUpdate = False
        MsgBox "This field is not to edit. Thnks"
        MKDataGrid1.AllowUpdate = False
        cmdAdd.visible = True
        cmdAdd.SetFocus
        cmdAdd.visible = False
    Else
        MKDataGrid1.AllowUpdate = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you installed the control you are using on the new machine? The "MKDataGrid" ? There will be an install package that you need to run.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a key value as an argument to KeyPress?

Comment: @Rob exactly, no arguments in a KeyPress handler. All he had to do was read the error he pasted `procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name`

Comment: @markJ -- You are exactly correct i have to register the vb6datagrid.ocx on my computer for this , i have register this .ocx on my machine but now it is showing error like : Name conflicts with the existing module,project or object library.

Comment: In vb6 ,I have gone in projects >> Components >> and then in designers i have unchecked some controls but doing this it shows like : "Can't remove control or reference; in use" , but in my original code directory those components is uncheck .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your declaration for the event got messed up.  Generally speaking, the KeyPress event takes the parameter `KeyAscii As Integer`.  I recommend temporarily remarking out your routine and then selecting the KeyPress event manually from the dropdown in the code window.  Then copy your previous content back into the KeyPress that VB inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I have to register the vb6datagrid.ocx on my computer for this , i have register this .ocx on my machine , actually i have again copy the new code in my machine from my old machine and before runing it i have open Project >> components >> designers and from there selected the require components and have removed the unwanted , and then i have run the project so again i get the error but when i go to view object there again i find the object missing so i have placed the datagrid  and then its running fine :)